# Drag and drop onto Python script in Windows Explorer

Tags: python, windows, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

I would like to drag and drop my data file onto a Python script and have it process the file and generate output. The Python script accepts the name of the data file as a command-line parameter, but Windows Explorer doesn't allow the script to be a drop target.

Is there some kind of configuration that needs to be done somewhere for this work?

Comment: i think it just works if you installed python from the windows setup installer (basically if you can double click to run a python script)

Comment: On Windows 10, I had to double click on the PY file and open with Python once in order for the drop handler to be recognized.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Sure. From a [mindless technology article called "Make Python Scripts Droppable in Windows"](http://mindlesstechnology.wordpress.com/2008/03/29/make-python-scripts-droppable-in-windows/), you can add a drop handler by adding a registry key:

> Here’s a registry import file that you can use to do this. Copy the
>   following into a .reg file and run it
>   (Make sure that your .py extensions
>   are mapped to Python.File).
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shellex\DropHandler]
> @="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"
> ```

This makes Python scripts use the WSH drop handler, which is compatible with long filenames. To use the short filename handler, replace the GUID with `86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D`.

A comment in that post indicates that one can enable dropping on "no console Python files (`.pyw`)" or "compiled Python files (`.pyc`)" by using the `Python.NoConFile` and `Python.CompiledFile` classes.

Comment: Where do you drop the file? Into the console window? Or onto the script file icon? I'm not following.

Comment: Thank you @Blair for your solution. I'm a beginner and I get the error **No such file or directory** after dropping. You can fix this by adding the following at the beginning of the script : 
`exepath = sys.argv[0]
if '\\' in exepath:
 os.chdir(exepath[:exepath.rfind('\\')])`

Comment: This information is outdated. The WSH drop handler was added to Python's installer in 2.6.1 (2008-12). However, a new drop handler was created for 3.6.0 (2016-12) and 3.5.3 (2017-01) because the WSH handler doesn't support Unicode paths. As long as .py files are associated with the `Python.File` progid, this should just work for all versions of CPython that are currently supported on Windows. But it's a good idea to install 3.5.3+ to get the new drop handler.

Comment: @Norfeldt I have a clunky error printing thing at https://github.com/endolith/waveform_analysis/blob/master/scripts/wave_analyzer_launcher.py

Comment: @eryksun Can you add this information to [halanson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617351/3357935)?

Comment: Can anyone clarify what is meant by "Make sure that your .py extensions are mapped to Python.File"? I have .py files set to open with python.exe by default, but this reg script isn't allowing me to drag drop on them.

Answer (score 46):

write a simple shell script (`file.bat`)

```
"C:\python27\python.exe" yourprogram.py %*
```

where `%*` stands for the all arguments you pass to the script.

Now drag & drop your target files on the `file.bat` icon.

Comment: How do you access the argument list in Python?

Comment: You can access each argument by `for arg in sys.argv[1:]: print(arg)`

Comment: Seems like the files are in a random order. Any way to preserve the order in which they were selected?

Comment: @Gillespie the order in which items are selected is not preserved correctly by Windows: for example, when I drag and drop .mp3 files into VLC, the last item I selected will be the first in the playlist.

Comment: @Gillespie I think reversing the order will fix this

Answer (score 19):

With an installed python - at least 2.6.1 - you can just drag and drop any file on a python script.

```
import sys
droppedFile = sys.argv[1]
print droppedFile
```

`sys.argv[0]` is the script itself. `sys.argv[n+1]` are the files you have dropped.

Comment: This answer is the simplest and easiest.  Also, tested to work with py2exe (using Python 3.3) after it has been converted to an exe.

Comment: This works, but like other solutions, it seems like the files are in a random order. Any way to preserve the order in which they were selected?

Comment: @Gillespie not really. Try to click and drop the first file in your selection instead of some file in the mid-selection. Depending on your use case you could also use an internal sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

Try using py2exe.  Use py2exe to convert your python script into a windows executable.  You should then be able to drag and drop input files to your script in Windows Explorer.  You should also be able to create a shortcut on your desktop and drop input files onto it.  And if your python script can take a file list you should be able to drag and drop multiple files on your script (or shortcut).

Answer (score 3):

Create a shortcut of the file. In case you don't have python open .py files by default, go into the properties of the shortcut and edit the target of the shortcut to include the python version you're using. For example:

Target:    C:\Python26\python.exe < shortcut target path>

I'm posting this because I didn't want to edit the Registry and the .bat workaround didn't work for me.

Comment: while i didn't follow this perfectly, this answer did expose my issue of my target of my python script was set by default to "open with" VS code instead of python.  changing it to python fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

1). create shortcut of .py
2). right click -> properties
3). prefix "Target:" with "python" so it runs the .py as an argument into the python command
or
1). create a .bat
2). python some.py %*

these shortcut versions are simplest for me to do what i'm doing
otherwise i'd convert it to a .exe, but would rather just use java or c/c++

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but none of the answers on this page worked for me.
I managed to enable/fix the drag and drop onto `.py` scripts using:

1. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py` -> Set default value to `Python.File`
2. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\Open` -> Create a key called `Command` with default value `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`
3. `CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\py.exe\open\command` ->  Create keys if the don't exist and set the default value to `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`
4. `CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\ShellEx` -> create key `DropHandler` with default value `{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}`

That's it. Test it by dragging a file onto the python script:

```
import sys

args = sys.argv
print(args)
```

Comment: This worked for me, although remember to terminate explorer.exe and start it again. Also, not sure if it's normal but it ends up with a truncated filename like 829897~1.JSO instead of the real `82989762511648_11612593811973.json`, but trying to open the path works as expected.

Comment: Found the solution to my own problem, instead of {86C... as suggested in Step 4, instead use {60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C} to get the better DropHandler which supports long names.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use argv in .py script but still can't drag files to execute,
this could be solved by simply *using Python Launcher (with rocket icon)*

the script property "Open File" was set as python.exe,
which has no knowledge that the script needs command-line arguments "%*"

Refer to: https://bugs.python.org/issue40253