# Setting document as windows explorer drop target with additional arguments

Tags: registry, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

My application is a sort of "scripting" system. I've made the "scripts" usable as drop targets using info from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142844/drag-and-drop-onto-python-script-in-windows-explorer), however, the default action is to open the script for editing.  To run it, you need to pass a `/r` argument.  Is there any way to either: a. use the *Run* verb, or b. pass the extra argument?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob]
@="MyApp Job"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shell\Run]
@="&Run"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shell\Run\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe\" /r \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shellex]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppJob\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.myJob]
@="MyAppJob"
```

(Program names have been changed above.)

I've tried adding a key `"Verb"="Run"` to the `DropHandler` subkey, but of course, it isn't that simple.

I know I could set *Run* as the default verb, but I'd prefer not to have to if at all possible.

Comment: So just to be 100% clear - when you drop a second file on to the script file, you want it to run the script via some executable in the form `myapp.exe /r target_script.myjob dropped_file.xyz`? If so, one option would be to create a second "dummy" executable that handles these situations and passes the appropriate parameters over to `myapp.exe`.

Comment: @Polynomial that's exactly what I'm after, but I can't see how to set it up - at least, without having to create a "dummy executable" for every script.

Comment: Good point. You may have to write your own shell extension DLL using IDropHandler to make this work properly. This would allow you to override the default verb.

Comment: So, it's back to battling with non-compiling MSDN c++ code... Fun.

Comment: COM is so lovely. Enjoy ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the answer, as suggested in comments, was to create my own ShellExtension dll.  I took a look at the microsoft provided example, but it wouldn't compile, and an example on CodeProject didn't make much sense (I think it was written for a different version of VS).

After some googling, however, I discovered this [C# codeproject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529515/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Drop-Handlers), which introduced me to [SharpShell](http://sharpshell.codeplex.com/), which is a C# library for shell extensions.  This simplified matters a whole lot:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.ClassOfExtension, ".myjob")]
public class MyAppDropHandler : SharpDropHandler
{
    protected override void DragEnter(DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        dragEventArgs.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    protected override void Drop(DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = this.SelectedItemPath,
                Verb = "Run",
                Arguments = String.Join(" ", list.Select(s => String.Format("\"{0}\"", s)))
            }
        }.Start();
    }
}
```

I then followed the instructions for registering the extension [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus), and it appears to work great.

Comment: Cool, I wrote the library it's great to see someone getting some use out of it!