# Is it possible to pass arbitrary arguments to a function in a non-input way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a shortcut method such as dragging a file to pass the filename of the dragged file as a parameter to the open() function.
For example, there are two files 00.py and 11.py. I drag 11.py onto 00.py and let go (open 11.py with 00.py), while "11.py" (file name) is passed as an argument to the open() function in 00.py.

Comment: What operating system and desktop environment are you using? Does it allow you to drag a file onto a script to launch the script with the file as an argument? I'm not familiar with that affordance.

Comment: Win10 operating system, the desktop environment is default, I don't know if I can pass the file as a parameter to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @[PPP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19680351/ppp) and thanks for this interesting question!

I found a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142844/drag-and-drop-onto-python-script-in-windows-explorer) here on stackoverflow and used it as used it as a starting point.

#### Enabling drag-and-drop

Looks like you can't just drag-and-drop onto any kind of file. It has to be an "executable" file (e.g. `.exe`, `.bat`, etc.). I set up a minimal example on my machine:

[image]

So I can't drag-and-drop `drag_me.txt` directly onto `opener.py`, but drag-and-drop works with `drop_here.bat` (because Windows recognizes the batch job as "executable" file)

#### Output

*In the console output below, I redacted the absolute path of `drag_me.txt` for privacy reasons*

```
Reading file 'C:\<redacted_for_privacy>\drag_me.txt'

Hello!

Press Enter to exit...
```

#### `drag_me.txt`

This is the file you want to open with your Python script. In this example, it just contains the string `Hello!`

#### `drop_here.bat`

This batch job "accepts" the dropped file and calls your Python script.

```
python opener.py %*
```

- `python opener.py` executes the Python script using the system interpreter. If you're using a virtual environment, replace `python` with the path to the interpreter you're using (e.g. `C:\venv\my_project\Scripts\python`)
- `%*` passes all arguments into the Python script. In this case, "all arguments" corresponds to `drag_me.txt`

#### `opener.py`

This is the Python script that opens `drag_me.txt` and prints its contents. The filename is taken from [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv), which contains the command line arguments:

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name

`argv[0]` is the script name (`opener.py`), so `argv[1]` is our desired filename.

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]

print(f"Reading file '{filename}'\n")

with open(filename) as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    
print(data)
input("\nPress Enter to exit...")
```

- The `input` statement isn't required. It just keeps the command prompt open so you have a chance to see the console output.

#### Fun fact

You can also execute the batch job from the command line:

```
drop_here drag_me.txt
```

#### Alternative: Create an executable

Instead of using the batch job, you can create an executable from your Python script (e.g. using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)):

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller opener.py --onefile
```

*With the `--onefile` option, everything is packed into a single `.exe` file instead of a folder containing multiple file.*

Here, I copied `opener.exe` from the `dist` folder:

[image]

I should note, however, that using PyInstaller comes with its own caveats (e.g. having to make sure everything is packed correctly).

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks a lot.
But then I thought of a consequent problem. Can I have the same effect if I convert the python script to an exe file?

Comment: @PPP Good point! I added a section to my answer about creating an executable

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem perfectly. I also tried it myself and found that there is a method without converting it into exe and bat files: (on Windows operating system) setting the default opening method of python script files to python.exe can also achieve the effect of passing parameters by dragging